# Rails FB GRAPH image not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, fbconnect

I'm working on Rails app using Facebook Graph everything was working fine and then suddenly images stop loading for user_pages, i debug and found the following error,

**{
   "error": {
      "message": "The 'manage_pages' permission must be granted before impersonating a user's page.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190
   }
}**

Any idea why it start happening. Please see attached screen-shot  [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

30th April was the last date when Facebook stopped supporting older versions of the App. I am not 100% sure but it seems you need to go to your developer account and submit a review request for your app with additional permissions.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions let me check this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you missed the news on Facebook's API upgrade - just like me. More information here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/api-v1-deprecation and https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/04/28/april-30-migration/

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, Let me check this.